# How to clone Linode virtual machine to local Hyper-V VM?

Tags: linux, hyper-v, ubuntu-14.04, cloning

Is it possible (somehow easily) to clone an existing Linode virtual machine, which is based on Ubuntu 14, to our own Hyper-V environment as an Ubuntu 14?

Or is it possible to clone (files, setting etc.) of one Ubuntu 14.04 to an other  existing Ubuntu 14.04? So that everything in that Ubuntu installation is exactly like it was in the other installation, every file, every setting etc.? If so, how to achieve that?

I am looking for an easy way to transfer sites and MySQL databases from one virtual machine to an other.

Answer (score 0):

There will be at least some differences like Linode's custom kernel or Hyper-V Linux Integration Services (LIS).

For changing platforms it might be simpler to rebuild new. At least it is a useful exercise to determine if you can re-create your installation and services from scratch.

So, new blank VM on Hyper-V, install desired OS version, copy or template out config files, restore databases from backups. Configuration management tools like Ansible or Puppet can help to apply the same state consistently.

Within one platform cloning is easy. [Here is how to clone your Linode.](https://linode.com/docs/platform/disk-images/clone-your-linode/)

Answer (score 0):

You can instal P2V tool (Disk2vhd) in your server linode. This tool can do snapshot from physical disk server to virtual disk (vhd, vhdx...)

Next Steep is download this archive in your local server and to create a virtual machine using virtual disk created.